# Proper installation of a three-way shower

Tags: plumbing, shower

I recently purchased this shower kit: http://soak.com/300mm-square-stainless-steel-head-handheld-&-four-body-jets--thermostatic-mixer-shower-kit_p31112937.htm. It has three outputs: overhead shower head, hand-held shower head, and side jets. There are then three controls: two one-way control, and one two-way controls.

I recently paid a plumber to install this in my bathroom, and I have just returned to find that things are not as I would have expected. One of the one-way controls is for temperature, as expected. However, the other one-way control is for the hand-held shower, and the two-way control is for changing between the overhead shower and the side jets. This means that I cannot use the overhead shower and the side jets simultaneousy....but I thought that was the whole point!

What I had expected, is that the one-way valve would be used to control the side jets, and then the two-way valve would be used to decide between the overhead or the hand-held shower. This is the set up I have seen everywhere else, to my memory.

So, my question is, can I accuse my plumber of installing the shower incorrectly? Or has he actually done a standard job with a standard configuration, and it would have been up to me to brief him beforehand as to which way I wanted it configured? Unfortunately, he has taken away the instructions, so I cannot see what the original instructions said.

Comment: I couldnt find the manual online.  Ask soak.com for a PDF of it.  What the manual says has everything to do with whether the plumber made a mistake, until you can get a copy (or some else finds online) this question is not real answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the setup you wanted has been the way I have seen similar arrangements, and seems intuitive, but the product description for the mixing valve unit says "controls the water flow **to your outlet of desire**".

My thought is that a plumber who cares about pleasing his client would have asked prior to roughing it in, but I don't think you have any legal standing.

> These shiny chrome plated mixer valves do much more than adding a designer look to your bathroom. They are convenient and safe to use with a 3 Way diverter. One knob controls the water flow to your outlet of desire, the other controls temperature and the third control water flow. To protect you and your family from scalding these valves are fitted with leading Vernet thermostatic control. Pre-set at 38 degrees this system prevents any water above this temperature from leaving the shower, for further safety it is enabled with an automatic shutdown if the cold water supply ever fails.